# Folder Redirection does not sync files back to share folders

Tags: windows-server-2008, group-policy, folder-redirection

I have a problem with folder redirection on Windows 7 client + Windows 2008 Server R2. The problem is files created in redirected folders (e.g. My Documents) never get synced back to the server. It turned out that for some reason these folders are in offline mode all the time, even after logoff or restart.

[image: screenshot]

The client is a fresh install and we did not set anything regarding offline files. I wonder if there is any group policy settings that make redirected folders synced with the server correctly without having to force it on the client machine?

Answer (score 1):

You can view the group policy settings in effect by running the command: `gpresult /z > gp.txt`

The applicable settings and the scope (machine or user) are below.  You may want to test "Synchronize all offline files before logging off".  Enabling this setting forces a "Full Synchronization", and "a full synchronization synchronizes automatically cached files as well."  This would probably cause a noticeable delay during the logoff process.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc961553.aspx

```
Policy Setting Name Scope
Action on server disconnect Machine
Administratively assigned offline files Machine
Allow or Disallow use of the Offline Files feature  Machine
At logoff, delete local copy of user's offline files    Machine
Configure Background Sync   Machine
Configure Slow link speed   Machine
Configure slow-link mode    Machine
Default cache size  Machine
Enable Transparent Caching  Machine
Encrypt the Offline Files cache Machine
Event logging level Machine
Exclude files from being cached Machine
Files not cached    Machine
Initial reminder balloon lifetime   Machine
Limit disk space used by offline files  Machine
Non-default server disconnect actions   Machine
Prevent use of Offline Files folder Machine
Prohibit 'Make Available Offline' for these file and folders    Machine
Prohibit user configuration of Offline Files    Machine
Reminder balloon frequency  Machine
Reminder balloon lifetime   Machine
Remove 'Make Available Offline' Machine
Subfolders always available offline Machine
Synchronize all offline files before logging off    Machine
Synchronize all offline files when logging on   Machine
Synchronize offline files before suspend    Machine
Turn off reminder balloons  Machine
Turn on economical application of administratively assigned Offline Files   Machine
Action on server disconnect User
Administratively assigned offline files User
Event logging level User
Initial reminder balloon lifetime   User
Non-default server disconnect actions   User
Prevent use of Offline Files folder User
Prohibit 'Make Available Offline' for these file and folders    User
Prohibit user configuration of Offline Files    User
Reminder balloon frequency  User
Reminder balloon lifetime   User
Remove 'Make Available Offline' User
Synchronize all offline files before logging off    User
Synchronize all offline files when logging on   User
Synchronize offline files before suspend    User
Turn off reminder balloons  User
```